# Cross Correlation: using to detect signal patterns?

Tags: convolution, signal-processing, correlation

I understand *correlation* is defined as below and have questions on using the concept for signal pattern detection.  I'm relatively new to this topic so appreciate anyone sending me in the best direction.

$$
a,f,g : S \rightarrow Y 
$$
$$
a(t) = (f \star g)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau) g(\tau + t) d\tau
$$

I would like to find the best shifted matches of $g$ over $f$, so I:
$$
F = argmax_{x \in S}(a(t))
$$
Is it an exact match:
$$
D(f,g,t) = \forall \tau\in S(\delta_{f(\tau)g(\tau+t)} = 1)
$$
$$
MatchesShift = \{t : t \in F \land D(f, g, t)\}
$$

Does this look correct to find best correlation and then exact matches?

I'm assuming more complex matching is performed by testing all the subsets of $g$.  Appreciate any guidance there